# Executing Script after serializeFileUpload

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I don't know if it is possible, but I like to show a picture after uploading it into the Library.
As soon as I want to cascade the serializeFileUpload I get an error and the method comment also states that serializeFileUpload may be the only callback.
My code so far:

```
html fileUpload
...
id: #fileUpload;
onChange: (html jQuery ajax 
    serializeFileUpload: (html jQuery id: inputString ));
callback: [ :f | self handleNewFile: f]
```

Is there a way to have the jQuery replace #fileUpload with the uploaded image?

Thanks

Max

Implementation in JQAjax>>serializeFileUpload:aQuery

```
    self
    data:
        ((((JSStream on: 'var formdata = new FormData()'),
         ((aQuery copy attributeAt: 'name') assignLocalTo: 'name'),
         (((aQuery property: 0) access: 'files') assignLocalTo: 'files'),
         (JSStream on:'for(i=0;i<files.length;i++) formdata.append(name,files[i])'),
         (JSStream on: 'return formdata')) asFunction) apply: #());
    url: self renderContext actionUrl;
    type: 'POST';
    cache: false;
    processData: false;
    contentType: false
```

Comment: `serializeFileUpload:` is not a standard Seaside message. Maybe you can show its implementation here.

Comment: hhmm.. this is in JQAjax: '"Upload the file in the field identified by aQuery using FormData. Cannot be composed with any other callback."
 
 self
  data:'

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I was looking in the wrong image. I wrote the method myself and did not even remember :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use the ajax onsucces callback?

```
(html jQuery ajax
   ...
   onSuccess: ((html jQuery id: #fileUpload) replaceWith: [:r | ... ]))
```

Comment: You mean like that: `html jQuery ajax 
      serializeFileUpload: (html jQuery id: inputString );
      onSuccess: ((html jQuery id: inputString) replaceWith:`?  Does not work unfortunately, the onSuccess part gets executed immediately when loading the page.

Comment: It works with onSuccess but only if you wrap the replaceWith into a script:  onSuccess: (html jQuery ajax  
       script: [ :s | s << ((s jQuery id: inputString) replaceWith: [`

Comment: This depends if the value of the success script can be evaluated before the ajax call or if it can be only constructed after the file uploaded. Good to see that it works.